# append data to url in android

Tags: android

In my android application I am trying to append data to url. But the data is not appending .Below is my code. Please correct me.

```
URL url=new URL("http://220.226.22.57:8780/WEB-3/client/requests/sgduTimeStampRequest.action");

    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    conn.setRequestProperty("aContentType","text/plain");
    conn.setRequestProperty("aBody","modified_since=3491039964");
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setDoOutput(true); 
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    SGDUParser parser=new SGDUParser(context);
    parser.parseUpdateBinaryFile(conn.getInputStream());
```

Please share your valuable suggestions.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: why there is additional 'a' in property names? `aContentType` and `aBody` ?

Answer (score 1):

The raw HTTP Request with POST should look like as follows:

```
POST /login.jsp HTTP/1.1
Host: www.mysite.com 
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0
Content-Length: 27
Content-Type: text/plain

userid=joe&password=guessme
```

You need to call `conn.getContent()`

Comment: Thanks Ankit.But i am not clear with what you are trying to say.Could you please share some code with me.

Answer (score 0):

In the code posted by you... you are not appending data to url or in words you are not making any get request. Here you are making Post request to url.